# Multi Argument Input String

Tags: java, input

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to find an easy way to input multiple arguments in one String and pass parts of it on to get computed.

For example, terminal instructions are usually a String of multible instructions  `sudo foo bar = [sudo][foo][bar]`

I don't know how to do this in java, or how it's supposed to be done.

**So far I've tried**

```
ArrayList<Integer> threadList = new ArrayList();


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);




    public void printOptions(){
        System.out.println("[1]          > New Primefactordevision");
        System.out.println("[Number]     > Check Status of [Number]");
        System.out.println("[x] [Number] > Terminates Primefactordivision of [Number]");
        System.out.println("[x]          > Terminate");

    }

    public void chooseOperation(){
        printOptions();
        String choice = scanner.next();

        switch(choice){
            case "1":{}
            case "Number":{}
            case String.format("x %s",threadList.get(*choice- x somehow*).toString()):{}
            case "x":{}
        }
```

The program is supposed to terminate a thread, computing primefactors out of an integer, when you type `x [integer contained by threadList]`.

So basically the String has 2 arguments. `[x]` and `[integer]`.

While it's not a problem to use `x` plus a defined `integer` as static parameter, it's a problem to have part of the choice parameter dynamically allocated from somewhere else, being conditional.

How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Afraid I'm not sure what you're asking - do you want to determine if a string contains x, a space, and then a number? If so a regex would be the best fit for that.

Comment: why not the same? and use split or regex to get the seperate parts

Comment: feel free to answer the question

Comment: @berry120 if I understand him right, he wants to get an array of Strings from "[sudo][foo][bar]" with elements "sudo", "foo" and "bar"

Comment: @BlkPengu I have answered your question. feel free to try it out

Comment: @Stultuske sudo foo bar was just an example of an multi arugment input string. I'm trying to have an input composed of the letter x and an integer, of which the integer is to be computed further.

Comment: why would that change the way to extract it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate my comment was to BlkPengu's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to have an input composed of the letter x and an integer, of which the integer is to be computed further

If you want to determine if a string matches the format "x 123", where 123 is a number that may vary (and then extract that number), a regex with a matcher is your best bet.

```
String inputStr = "x 123";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("x (\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
if(matcher.find()) {
    String num = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(num);            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following program will read a string and an int from the console and print them

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String s = sc.next();
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(s+"/"+i);
        }
    }
}
```